# how to get max offset of scrollview in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollview, offset

I manged to get and set scrollerOffest as :

```
double horizonatalOffest = sv.HorizontalOffset; 
Debug.WriteLine("horizonlat offset: " + horizonatalOffest.ToString()); 
sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(2000);
```

The problem is how to get the max offset.   Say I have the scroller 0 to 50000. So how can I get max offset?   `Scrollview.HorizontalOffset` returns current offset position? Note that My scroller grows/shrinks during run time.

Comment: What do you need this for? There are guides on how to create Twitter-like scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum offset for the `ScrollViewer` will depend on its content. Obtain the child of the `ScrollViewer`, and obtain its height via its `ActualHeight` property. You then subtract the `ScrollViewer` `ActualHeight` property value to give you the maximum offset.

Comment: Just for the record, that won't work. The ScrollViewer's ActualHeight/Width won't ever be larger than screen size.

Comment: I think you mis-read, I stated that you obtain the ActualHeight of the  *child* of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Oh, right you are. Then there's just the problem with the maximum offset being larger than the actual content, due to the scroll "bounce" effect. Oh, the joys of scrollbars.